# Delete DataGridView row that isn't showing ID

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Windows Form Application with a DataGridView.

AutoGenerateColumns is false so I have added the columns manually

I left out the ID field from the added columns and added a DataGridViewButtonColumn column.

How do I associate the ID to the row without displaying it so that the Delete button deletes the row it is on?

Comment: You can leave the ID column in the datagrid and just set it as hidden. That way you'll be able to interact with it but users won't see it.

Comment: Looks like `dgv.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;`

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thanks @Forklift!

Comment: Cheers, @toad happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @forklift comment. Making the column not visible worked fine.